# Counting the same cells in Excel

Tags: excel, search, count

I have a list of more than 2000 entries. I need to count the same entries and unique ones. For example, Excel will show that the cell, 'Out of cartridge', repeated 3 times. However, since I have more than 2000 cells, I can't use COUNTIF function because I can't write what to search in formula for thousands of entries. So, is there any formula I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achived by applying [Pivot](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html), do the following

1. Select the entire column which you need to count
2. Select Insert -> PivotTable option
3. On Pivot Table filed list drag and drop the same field to Row Lables and values.

[image]